# JavaScript: Convert 8 am of 5.5 timezone to UTC hour?

Tags: javascript

I tried Googling but almost all of the examples seems to be converting a specific date to UTC. I am just concerned about converting "8 A.M. Indian Standard Time" to UTC.

Comment: I suggest you to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)! cheers.

Comment: I don't know whether IST has daylight savings or not, but in general timezones do, so you will have to convert a concrete date to get the correct time. However, if you have such a limited use case and can ignore DST… then simply subtract 5.5 hours…!? That's not that problematic. Or simply use *the current date* and do the usual conversion which you have already seen many examples of.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else faces this problem, in future, I solved it in the following way:

`moment("08:00:00", "hh:mm:ss").utcOffset(5.5, true)`